Do you need an infant seat in Spanish taxis?
I will be travelling to Spain (Malaga) in the near future with my one year old child. I plan to take public transit most of the time but may use the occasional taxi.
Do the local regulations mandate I bring my infant seat for use in the taxi ?

UK answer: taxis are exempt from the general rules for child seats but have their own rules, for practicality. For example if you are travelling by train with three children, and going on by taxi, would it be reasonable for a) you to bring three seats with you, b) for the taxi to carry all the different child seats for various ages, three of each?

... and the general advice is to travel in the rear seat, cradling the infant. Wear a seat belt yourself, but do not wrap it over the child. Better advice is to wear a baby harness yourself: but again, don't put your own seat belt around the child. In an accident, the child may be crushed by your weight.

A bit of searching in Spanish and I found this. In short:

If your entire journey is within municipal limits, a child seat is not required in a rented car, in a taxi (or Uber or similar)
If your final destination is outside these limits (in practice, it means the journey will involve roads with max speed higher than 50 km/h), the child seat is required without exceptions

Bear in mind that you could be fined even if stopped by the police in a city center, if they find out you're travelling somewhere out of the city. On the other hand, if you're driving in a contiguous built-up area and you happen to cross from one municipality to another adjacent one (such as from Barcelona to Sant Adrià de Besòs), you're probably okay. Just make sure you stay off beltways and freeways with higher speed limits.

Taxis are not legally required to provide child car seats for young children. However, some larger cities like Madrid and Barcelona do require taxis to have infant or booster seats available.
